# fetch current product id on cart page

Tags: magento2

I want to fetch all product id that selected on cart page in phtml file.
someone please send me some link or tutorial that i want to fetch product id's that selected in cart page through phtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

 $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
     echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
     echo "<br />";            
  }
```